# ASP.NET: Gridview last column, "fill" option like in DGV for VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, datagridview

I was wondering if there's any way in ASP.NET Gridview to have the last column use the same "fill" option as in DGV's in VB.NET. I need the last column to fill the entire rest of the space in my table.

Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I simply added in a percent value for the width of the last column and it's working as needed. :)

Update:
Basically, what is going on here is that everything as far as widths and constraints are defaulted (generally) to the "auto" setting. I realized that if I put a percentage width value as the last column width everything else would fill in as needed.